# Get all characters given the account username

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I have only an account in LOTRO, but I have played on several servers.

Is it possible to get a list of all the characters I've created and in which server they are if I give my username? Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I just found this website: [altfinder](http://lotroaltfinder.net/) but it says:

[image]

There I only can get the chars that I've created before august 1st 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, no.

Turbine severely restricted their API; causing developers to have to remove features and close applications.